# Can't assign relative path to image source in Javascript after applying KB4486474 to IE11

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer-11, src

I have code that has worked for years without any issue until Microsoft's latest Cumulative Security Update came out this February. When KB4486474 is installed for IE11 (Version 11.590.17134.0, Update Versions: 11.0.110), the following line now throws an "Access Is Denied" error.

```
o.src = "/img/menuTick.png";
```

Variable "o" is an IMG element. This only seems to affect assignments to the src property of an IMG element as far as I can see. The only way I've found to get around this is assigning the full URL.

```
o.src = "http://mywebsite.com/img/menuTick.png";
```

or:

```
var l = window.location;
o.src = l.href.replace(l.pathname, "/img/menuTick.png");
```

If I uninstall the KB4486474 update for IE11, the original code works fine again.

Has anyone else come across this issue, and if so, is there any way around this as I literally have thousands of assignments to relative paths in the code, and don't want to have to replace with the above fix for every one of them?

Answer (score 0):

o.src = "\img\menuTick.png";

or

o.src = l.href.replace(l.pathname, "\img\menuTick.png");

Comment: I can't use backslash as it's a known issue. I'm using forward slash in my relative path, but it seems relative paths are not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue from [KB4486474](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4486474/cumulative-security-update-for-internet-explorer-february-12-2019) update. After user install this security update, Internet Explorer may not load images that have a backslash () in their relative source path.

[image]

This issue was resolved in Cumulative update [KB4491113](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4491113/cumulative-update-for-internet-explorer-february-19-2019) for Internet Explorer: February 19, 2019.

So I suggest you to install [4491113](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4491113/cumulative-update-for-internet-explorer-february-19-2019) update which may help you to solve your issue.

Comment: If you look at my code snippet, I'm not using backslash at all, I'm using forward slash. Besides, if you re-read my original post, it's the relative path that isn't working, only full URL does. This isn't to do with the backslash issue. Also, I can't install the update as I'm using Windows 10 with IE11, and there is no Windows 10 update package for KB4991113.

Comment: Can you please again try to check whether you are able to download the KB4991113 or not? If still that update is not available on your machine than for a testing purpose, You can try to remove KB4486474 to check whether it corrects this issue or not. it can help to decide that this specific update had cause this issue or not.